# IE9 does not print the changed option in a dropdown list

Tags: css, printing, cross-browser, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-9

In a simple dropdown box in IE9, if the user changes the selection and then tries to print, the print will render the original option.

Say, I have

```
<option value="">Select one: </option>
<option value="1">Record 1</option>
<option value="2">Record 2</option>
<option value="3">Record 3</option>
```

By default, when the page is loaded, "Select one:" is displayed in this dropdown box. If I pick "Record 2", and then print the page, "Select one:" is printed out inside the box instead of "Record 2" which I have selected.

Firefox can print correctly. Other versions of IE can also do the job. But we would rather not use the compatibility view:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

Because in this case, though the selected value is correctly displayed inside the drop down box, many of our css styles are lost. (such as border-radius)

Does anyone have a good solution? Thanks.

Comment: I am absolutely bewildered by this bug. Running the page in "Compatability" mode also fixes the issue (but you are back to IE8 settings for CSS and such then).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a rough function that seems to do the trick, it needs to be tested thoroughly in your environment but seems to be OK at the moment:

```
if ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) === 9) {
                $("select").change(function () {
                    var selectedOpt = $(this).find("option:selected");
                    var originalDefaultOption = $(this).find("option[selected]");
                    var text = originalDefaultOption.html();
                    var val = originalDefaultOption.val();

                    originalDefaultOption.after("<option value='" + val + "'>" + text + "</option>");
                    originalDefaultOption.remove();
                    selectedOpt.attr("selected", true);
                });
            }
```

Basically, IE won't let you remove the 'selected=selected' attribute from the option, even with JavaScript. So I'm just copying the original default option into a new option tag, without copying the 'selected' attribute, and I'm putting the 'selected' attribute on the newly clicked option. Works in FF and IE9 & 8.

Comment: No problem. Its a ridiculous bug, a real head-desk-banger.